# Natbib errors: find which entry is causing them

Tags: errors, natbib, tools

When one is pestered with the all too familiar error message

```
! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations,
```

how does one find which entry is causing the problem? I'm aware of the many answers describing what may be causing the errors (e.g., a lack of a `year` field), but is there a tool which will list all entries that will cause errors for a given citation format?

Comment: Actually, this is by far not a familiar error, and not as trivially solved either. BibTeX and natbib are rather stable against missing fields in entries. Even if I have entries in which I only provide an author, or a title and year without author, the code does not break. If you get such an error, your problem is much more severe. Please provide a minimal example that demonstrates the error.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments. I didn't provide a MWE as I'm looking for a tool to find the location of the error in the general case, rather than trying to solve the problem in this specific case. The problem that caused this error was that an `@inbook` entry crossrefed to a `@book` entry, but the order of definitions was the wrong way round. In a bibtex file with tens of thousands of lines, this is an almost impossible error to find by hand if no details are given regarding which entry triggered it.

Comment: Your reputation points are now high enough you are allowed to vote up helpful answers. Please consider to do this with my answer below. It is the way to say "Thank You" here ... Usually an accepted answer is worth to be updated. You can upvote more than one answer, but you can only accept one answer as most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last you asked in your question:

> is there a tool which will list all entries that will cause errors for
>   a given citation format?

You can't see only package `natbib` or only the BibTeX file.  Both of them are a unit you have to test together.

Therefore there is only one "tool" you can use to test the BiBTeX file:

**LaTeX with calling package `natbib` and the complete BibTeX file.**

That can easy be done with the following MWE.   I added two `bib` files, one without errors, one with errors you all will find using my natbib-bibtex-test-mwe. Just move the comment from one command `\bibliography` to the other.

Command `\nocite{*}` shows **all** bib entrys (four in my example) in the resulting bibliography file.

Package `filecontents` is used to add both example bib files into the MWE so that only one file has to be compiled. In real just change `\jobname` to the filename of your bib file (no extention `.bib` please!).

natbib-bibtex-test-mwe:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}        % loading package filecontents
% writing file \jobname.bib, for example mb-bibtex.bib.
% Creating bib file without errors:
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}  
@Book{Companion.1994,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams.1980,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@misc{mozart:KV183,
  author  = {Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus},
  title   = {Sinfonie g-Moll},
  year    = {1773},
  address = {Salzburg},
  note    = {New K{\"o}chelverzeichnis Nr. 183, old version Nr. 25; 
             Erster Satz: Allegro con brio, Zweiter Satz: Andante, 
             Dritter Satz: Menuetto, Vierter Satz: Allegro},
}
\end{filecontents*}

% Creating bib file with errors:
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-error.bib}
@Book{adams,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.}
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980}
}
@article{einstein,
  title   = {Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
misc{mozart:KV183,
  author  = {Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus},
  title   = {Sinfonie g-Moll},
  year    = {1773},
  address = {Salzburg},
  note    = {New K{\"o}chelverzeichnis Nr. 183, old version Nr. 25; 
             Erster Satz: Allegro con brio, Zweiter Satz: Andante, 
             Dritter Satz: Menuetto, Vierter Satz: Allegro},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}         % bibliography style
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}    % better urls in bibliography

\begin{document}
Test the complete \texttt{.bib} file. \nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}   % needs package natbib
 \bibliography{\jobname}       % uses \jobname.bib, according to \jobname.tex
%\bibliography{\jobname-error} % uses \jobname.bib, according to \jobname.tex
\end{document}
```

Result with the error free BibTeX file:

[image]

Result with the not error free file (I have 2 errors and 6 warnings for the bib file. The two warnings about `filecontents` are okay!):

[image]

For me all throwed error messages and warnings are pretty clear.

A tip at last:  if you have a big BibTeX file, copy a part of it and test that part in a special test BiBTeX file, correct the errors and go on with the next part in a separate BibTeX test file and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This error is casued by the `.bst` file rather than by an entry in the `.bib` file.  As a rule, you must use natbib-compatible bst files with natbib:  `abbrvnat` rather than `abbrv`, `unsrtnat` rather than `unsrt` etc.

Comment: But when I try that (using unsrt instead of unsrtnat) everything works fine as well. Actually, there is not even a warning. From a short test there seems to be no way to mess up the bib-file or bst-file that much that this error occurs. Have you ever actually seen this particular error?

Comment: Natbib is very permissible, and can deal with generic bst files in some situation, esp. with numeric citation style.  However, author-year styles require author-year labels, and many non-natbib styles just do not work.

Comment: Many thanks for the solution, though I'm afraid I haven't accepted it as the question asked for a tool to isolate the cause of the error. Having found the cause of the error (`@inbook` and `@book` definitions given in the wrong order), the cause of the error was conceptually very much within the `.bib` file and not the `.bst` file.